# Get notification on a Java process termination

Tags: java

There is a console Java application which is supposed to run until it is stopped by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or closing the console window. How that application can be programmed to execute a clean up code before exit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a [Shutdown Hook](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/03/26/shutdownhook.html).

Basically you need to create a Thread which will perform your shutdown actions, and then [add it as a shutdown hook](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)). For example:

```
class ShutdownHook extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        // perform shutdown actions
    }
}

// Then, somewhere in your code

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook())
```

Answer (score 3):

A Shutdown hook is the way to go, but be aware that there is no guarantee that the code is actually executed. JVM crashes, power failures, or a simple "kill -9" on your JVM can prevent the code from cleaning up. Therefore you must ensure that your program stays in a consistent state even if it has been aborted abruptly.

Personally, I simply use a database for all state-storage. Its transactions model makes sure that the persistent storage is in a sane state no matter what happens. They spend years making that code fool-proof, so why should I waste my time on problems already solved.

Comment: @Thomas Morgner are u suggesting he should use a database for storing function variables, private class attributes and such?

Answer (score 1):

Program to delete temp file bat.bat when program is exited:

```
public class Backup {

    public static void createBackup(String s)
    {

        try{
            String fileName ="C:\\bat"+ ".bat";
            FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(fileName);
            String batquery="cd C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin"
                    + "\nmysqldump -uroot -proot bankdb > \""+s+".sql\""                    
                    +"\nexit";

            writer.append(batquery);
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}
        try{
            Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\bat.bat");

        }
        catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}
        ShutDownHook sdh=new ShutDownHook();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(sdh);
    }


}

  class ShutDownHook extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            File f=new File("c:/bat.bat");
            f.delete();
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code written inside a `Thread`s `run()` method will execute when the runtime object terminates...

```
class ShutdownHookclass extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        // perform shutdown actions
    }
}

//could be written anywhere in your code
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutdownHookclass())
```