# Java: Take action on process death?

Tags: java

I am debugging a Java app, which frequently involves killing the process. I would like to do some cleanup before the app dies. Is there a way to catch the event and react accordingly? (Sort of like catching a `KeyboardInterrupt` in Python.

**Update**: I tried adding this to `main()`, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Closing...");
            }
        });
```

The code does not get run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get notification on a Java process termination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264825/get-notification-on-a-java-process-termination)

Comment: How are you killing the process?

Comment: @developmentalinsanity hitting the red block in Eclipse.

Comment: @Rosarch Then you're probably out of luck. I don't think you get any chance to do anything if you stop it like that. It pretty much kills the JVM as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Rosarch unless the ugly hack I've just posted as an answer is of any use

Comment: I wonder if using a [posix compatibility package](http://www.bmsi.com/java/posix/posix-1.2.2/doc/posix/Signal.html) would let you trap `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT`. Of course, if killing the window sends `SIGKILL`, then you're out of luck, that signal is uncatchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a [shutdown hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

Be aware that this doesn't guarantee your hook will be called, so there is no bulletproof way to be 100% sure your cleanup will be actually done.

There is a limited timeframe when the JVM can do cleanup, and if you attempt to do too much in the hook, don't expect it will be done.

Answer (score 2):

If you're stopping the process via the "stop" button in Eclipse, then shutdown hook won't run. As far as I'm aware, there isn't any way to run a hook in that scenario - it pretty much kills the JVM with no chance for cleanup. If you were running from the commandline, CTRL+C would work, but I don't think you can do that from in eclipse very well.

UGLY HACK:

Add something like this at the start of main:

```
    JFrame killer = new JFrame("Killer");
    killer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    killer.setSize(100, 100);
    killer.setVisible(true);
```

Closing the resulting window will trigger a System.exit(), which should allow shutdown hooks to run. Of course, this won't work if the program is suspended in the debugger. YMMV.