# Killing a JFrame/Java when process finishes

Tags: java, process, jframe, kill

I've been trying to find an answer to this question for quite a while, and found many similar questions here on SO, but none of them seem to solve the issue.

So some background: I have a program that uses a JFrame. There is a button in the frame, and when the button is clicked it calls the following code to run a batch file:

```
String[] commands = new String[list.size()];
commands = list.toArray(commands);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
p.waitFor();
closeWindow();
```

The "commands" are the parameters that are passed into the Runtime.getRuntime.exec() method, so it includes things like the batch file name and other parameters. When the process is finished (i.e. when the batch file is done), I need the program to completely close the JFrame and kill the associated Java process found in the Windows task manager. However, this method for closing the window does not kill the process:

```
public void closeWindow(){
    WindowEvent close = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(close);
}
```

I have also tried methods like destroy(), dispose(), etc, but they always leave the same process running in the task manager. I know it's the associated process because I can't delete any files related to my Java program and batch file until I kill that Java process. Otherwise it tells me it can't be deleted because the file is in use by another process.

Is there a better way to close a window AND stop a java process when a batch file completes? By the way, the process that continues running is simply "Java(TM) Platform SE binary", from javaw.exe.

**EDIT:**

After some more debugging and messing around with the code, I discovered that the p.waitFor() does not wait for the process to complete. The "closeWindow()" method is called before Process p is complete. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Thread has been split since we narrowed it down a bit. Here is the new thread:

[p.waitFor() does not wait for process to complete (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585753/p-waitfor-does-not-wait-for-process-to-complete-java)

Comment: Did you try calling just `System.exit(0)`?

Comment: What is the frames `defaultCloseOperation` property set to?

Comment: System.exit(0) had no effect, it still does not kill the process. The defaultCloseOperation is set to EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Copy/pasted general tip on `exec` -  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Normally I would try to post an SSCCE but this code is far too extensive for that to be useful and/or convenient, for me OR the readers. It requires a lot of information from half a dozen classes, each with its own setup, layout, methods, etc

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264825/get-notification-on-a-java-process-termination

Comment: As to why `Process.waitFor()` exits early, could the subprocess you're creating be spawning another process (what the application appears to be) that it doesn't maintain an OS handle to, thus 'exiting' early?

Comment: @JesanFafon It shouldn't. The batch file simply copies files from one drive to another, and exits when it finishes. I'm not sure why that would cause the java program to see it as ended before it actually exits? Unfortunately I'm not as familiar with batch files and how they run, so I don't know if this is a common occurrence or not.

Comment: A further note: I found the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199119/runtime-exec-waitfor-doesnt-wait-until-process-is-done
However, adding the /wait command made no difference. The process still is not allowed to finish before the closeWindow method is called.