# p.waitFor() does not wait for process to complete (Java)

Tags: java, process

This is a spinoff of this thread: [Killing a JFrame/Java when process finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558377/killing-a-jframe-java-when-process-finishes)

I know this question has been asked various times here on SO but none of the answers seem to solve my problem. The issue I am having is this: I have a java program that calls a batch file. I need the batch file to finish before the Java program continues. For this I use the waitFor() method, which should wait until the process finishes. However, it doesn't. I found this thread, which suggests that the process waitFor() is actually waiting for is simply cmd.exe, which returns before the actual process does.
[Runtime.exec().waitFor() doesn't wait until process is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199119/runtime-exec-waitfor-doesnt-wait-until-process-is-done)
That thread recommends using the /wait command, but when I do it makes no difference. My code is very in-depth with several classes that all rely on one another, but here is an attempted SSCCE:

```
public class BatchFileRun(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("cmd.exe");
        list.add("/C");
        list.add("Start");
        list.add("/wait");
        list.add(("C:\\.....\\scripts\\myBatchFile.bat"));
        list.add("batchVariable");
        String[] commands = new String[list.size()];
        commands = list.toArray(commands);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        p.waitFor();
        closeWindow();
    }
    void closeWindow(){
        WindowEvent close = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(close);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The batch file simply operates on the variable passed into it as a parameter (batchVariable). All prior commands should be used to simply run the batch file. The problem is that the closeWindow() method is called before the process in the batch file is finished. Therefore, the Java process that appears in the Windows task manager remains running, even though it should close when closeWindow() is called (if I am using it correctly). I really need said process to close when the process running from the batch file is complete. I have tried different ways of running the batch file (using ProcessBuilder, for example), but no matter what I try I have the same problem.

Comment: I don't understand the motivation to use `start /wait` instead of just executing the batch file. Is it to avoid troubles with stdin/stdout?

Comment: I added /wait after reading the link I posted earlier. Originally I just had "start". "/wait" supposedly would force cmd.exe to only tell waitFor() that it was finished when the process in the batch file was complete. However, this was not the case and I ran into the same issue as before.

Comment: But why `start` at all?

Comment: I believe "start" is required to actually run the batch file, is it not?

Comment: The `cmd /c` part is necessary, instead of just naming the batch file as you could from the command line; `start` isn't. But note that there *is* the issue of consuming any output of the execution.

Comment: Interesting. I don't suppose the "start" is causing the Java process to remain open though, would it?

Comment: After removing "start" and "/wait", the batch file does indeed still run, but the process is never killed.

Comment: UPDATE: I take that back, it seems to work, except it runs the batch file in the background. I need for it to either a) run in the foreground, or b) run a progress bar (indeterminate) while the process is running. I suppose that's a question for another thread though. Feel free to post your comment as an answer (with a little elaboration for future readers) and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the batch file so it only finishes when the process it launches finishes.

Comment: How would you suggest I do that? I currently have it set to (for example) operate on the variable, echo the new value of the variable, then exit