# Java terminal/CMD prompt closing event

Tags: java, console, command-prompt

I have a Java application running in normal command prompt.
In my application i use JSSC Com port to listen to COM1.

I start my application using

`java -jar MyApp.java`

I searched and got that Java may hold the port for sometime after closing.
I don't want that. Port should immediately close.

**Question :**
When user clicks the 'X' button in the command prompt, java holds the port for some time and after sometime the port is released.

Comment: Ensure all your streams (InputStream, and OutputStream) are closed when the user closes the window. There is also a disconnect() method in the api.

Comment: You have to register shutdown hook check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264825/get-notification-on-a-java-process-termination and disconnect the port.

Comment: @Sterls...How will i get the event when the cmd prompt/terminal window is closed?

Comment: @Karthikeyan I have tried shutdown hook...but is not triggered when the cmd prompt/terminal window is closed